# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException trying using reloadSections

Tags: swift, uitableview, reload, sections

please I need help! it's 3 days that I'm getting crazy with an easy problem. I have a problem reloading a section in tableview in a viewController that I've called VersionController (as you can see in my code).
I have this two sections and I want that just can be open one section at time. so when I try to open and then close the same section it works perfectly. But when I open a section and the I try to open another different it crashes with this message: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". when in a normal way it should close the old section and open the last clicked.
in particular way I don't know why if open and I close the same section it works perfectly. But when I use THE SAME METHOD in the SAME WAY for open different section it crashes. Besides I try to use tableView.reloadData() instead of tableView.reloadSection and it works perfectly: so I don't think it's an OUTLET problem as I read in others post.

this is the code on VersionController in the function "didSelectRowAt":

```
    if indexPath.section-flag > 0 && indexPath.section-flag <= oLinguaBibbie!.count
    {

        if indexPath.section != openVersion
        {
            if openVersion != -1
            {
                print("\n\nENTRATO 1 - sezione vecchia: \(openVersion)\nSEZIONE NUOVA: \(indexPath.section)")
                //salvo la versione vecchia
                let sup = openVersion
                openVersion = indexPath.section
                let sec = IndexSet.init(integer: sup)
                tableView.reloadSections(sec, with: .fade)
                print("\nDopo il primo reloads")

            }
            else //non è stata ancora aperta nessuna sezione
            {
                print("\n\nENTRATO 2 - sezione vecchia: \(openVersion)\nSEZIONE NUOVA: \(indexPath.section)")
                openVersion = indexPath.section
            }
            //apro quella nuova
            print("\narrivato qui")
            //tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)
            let sec = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sec, with: .fade)
            print("\nFINE: CARICATO NUOVO")
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
        else //la devo chiudere perché ho cliccato sulla versione aperta
        {
            print("\n\nENTRATO 3 - sezione vecchia: \(openVersion)\nSEZIONE NUOVA: -1")
            openVersion = -1
            let sec = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sec, with: .fade)
            print("\nFINE: Chiuso lo stesso")
    }
```

openVersion keeps track of witch section is opened.

to see all my code you can download it here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i00nlwfp1r3b8a2/AADJvqdGocL-lZJ1-PFBIBB6a?dl=0
inside there is also a video showing the problem.
thank you all. please I'm desperate.

Comment: Probably the error you received is more descriptive. Show me more details of the error from the console.

Comment: Thank you man for the reply. The problems it says just that on my console. If you download the project, you can try it by your own and see it. let me know. Thank you so much.